# What is the difference in meaning between the question "did you ever do...?" and "have you ever done...?" without referring to any period in the past?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

What is the difference in meaning between the question *did you ever do something?* and *have you ever done something?* without referring to any period in the past? For example, in the 17th episode of the 6th season of *Friends*, Ross asks Joey the following.

> Ross: Hey Joe did… **Did you ever have a threesome?**
>
> Joey: (not quite sure of how to answer that) Well uh, look Ross I uh,
>   I think Carol’s great and I’m sure you’re a very attractive man, but
>   I….
>
> Ross: No! The reason I’m asking is that… I sorta had one last night.

I canno get why he didn't say *have you ever had...?*, which would make sense becase he didn't refer to any period of time in the past in the episode.

Comment: As a British English speaker, I _would_ say "Have you ever had...?" American usage is different.

Comment: AE often uses past simple, where BE uses present perfect, your example illustrates that perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Did you ever" would be better for something that you might have done in the past but wouldn't do now, like "Did you ever go to camp as a kid?", whereas "have you ever" implies that it's something that they may still be able to do now.  Knowing the context, I agree that "have you ever" would make more sense.